# My cat had a little bit of lactose-free chocolate milk, should I be worried?

Tags: cats, safety, poison

So my cat licked up the last bits of chocolate milk in my cup as my back was turned and I caught her and pulled her away from it. She vomited but otherwise she seems fine. The chocolate milk was lactose free as I’m lactose intolerant and it was only a small amount. Should I be concerned?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add what exactly the ingredients in the chocolate milk are? For example sugar? Or artificial sweetener, and if so, which?

Comment: I added a photo of the back of the carton.

Comment: While chocolate is fatal for cats, if she has vomitted, most of it should be out. However keep a close watch for any unusual behaviour. Do rush to the vet in the smallest of changes in behaviour.

Comment: Good news is that this milk contains only 0.4% cocoa, while sweet chocolate contains at least 30% and dark chocolate over 70% cocoa.

Comment: Someone with a better knowledge should answer this but I wouldn't concern the slightest.

Comment: I like to add, that this milk is not without lactose. Instead lactase enzym is added. This enzym is missed in people with lactose intolerance (and in cats). It should be the same in human and cats, so the cat should be able to use it too (but I am not absolutely sure).

Comment: @Allerleirauh I think this milk does not have lactose (the label lists ingredients and it says "Nil" (in other words, zero) for lactose content). And you are right, there is the enzyme called lactase that decomposes lactose into glucose and galactose. Lactase enzyme is extracted from microorganisms (most often from specific strains of yeasts) and the lactase is then added to the milk in the manufacturing process. After all the lactose has been broken down to glucose and galactose, the milk is pasteurized because the lactase enzyme is often not 100% pure and contains small amount of ...

Comment: @Allerleirauh ... other enzymes that can break down milk proteins and shorten its shelf life. What is more, the lactase enzyme could contain small amounts of active microorganisms that it was harvested from. For both of these reasons, after the lactase has broken down all the lactose, milk is pasteurized to deactivate all the enzymes and destroy all the microorganisms.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Source: [Making milk lactose free](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYyqZWWU9GU) video by NileRed.

Answer (score 5):

In general, you should watch for the following symptoms as indications of possible poisoning:

- diarrhea
- vomiting
- dizziness / vertigo
- signs of paralysis
- dilated pupils
- seizures
- salivating / drooling

Clinical symptoms in cats are to be expected when ingesting 20mg or more of Theobromine per kilogram of body weight.

Cocoa powder is around 14-26mg Theobromine per gram, and in your product about 1 gram of cocoa powder for the whole package (0.4% of approximated weight converting millilitres to grams directly, not accurate but accurate enough for our purposes).

This makes 14-26mg Theobromine if the whole package is ingested, so a couple of licks from the bottom of the cup, even considering there might be a concentration of undissolved powder, should not pose a significant danger.

*Even so, in a situation like this I would still call my vet to get their opinion on how to proceed.*

Answer (score -2):

Following up with bgse;

The big No-No for cats is an artificial sweetener called Xylitol. If that chocolate milk contained any of that, then I would take your cat to the vet because too much Xylitol can poison your cat. It also can poison any dog that ingests it. This is why you should always watch your pet around chocolate, gum, or any water flavoring.

However your cat may have vomited due to the sugar content.

According to [Bondvet.com](https://bondvet.com//b/can-cats-eat-sweets-what-you-should-know-about-cats-and-sugary-treats#:%7E:text=If%20your%20furry%20friend%20eats,problems%2C%20and%20other%20health%20issues.), "If your furry friend eats sugar, you might see vomiting, diarrhea, and discomfort. Symptoms can range from a mild to severe, depending how sensitive your cat is and what they ate. Plus, in the long-term, sugar consumption can cause weight gain, diabetes, tooth problems, and other health issues."

Comment: Please include some information to directly answer the question; you are technically right that xylitol is poisonous for cats, but the label visible on the photo attached to question does not list xylitol as ingredient; the question is about cocoa and not xylitol. Also, xylitol is not artificial sweetener, it is sugar substitute (xylitol is not artificial because it occurs naturally in some fruits and is industrially made from wood).

Comment: Sorry the image shows as copyright so i canot see the image.

Comment: Oh okay I understand. The ingredient list is: "full cream milk, sugar, milk solids, cocoa powder (0.4%), flavour (wheat maltodextrin), emulsifier (471), stabilizers (407, 412). Contains milk and cereals containing gluten. Liddelis lactose free milk uses the lactase enzyme."

Comment: Thank you ill look into it

Comment: Answer Edited..

Comment: Okay thanks for updating. Content of sugars in this milk is 7.9 g per 100 mL (I know you cannot view images, so I am telling this) this is quite high concentration of sugars and maybe you are right about sugar being the reason for vomiting, I don't know; the other answer does not mention sugars at all, so at least this is innovative and original thought of yours and I am happy about that. However, from the context of the question I could understand that the major concern is the fact that this milk is chocolate milk, and chocolate/cocoa is toxic to cats (and dogs, too) and your  ...

Comment: ... answer does not mention the subject of chocolate/cocoa at all; in short, chocolate is toxic to pets because cocoa plant produces the alkaloid theobromine that pets are unable to efficiently metabolize; please read [this article about theobromine poisoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theobromine_poisoning) and include some information in this context; thanks.

Comment: And please include some more essence beyond just mentioning the risk of theobromine poisoning; I think that person asking this question already knows that chocolate and other cocoa products are toxic to cats and that was why the question was asked in the first place; it is more helpful if the answers actually tries to assess and estimate the level of danger and informs what to do in case of poisoning (like the answer of bgse).